# How to run previous command with another command

Tags: bash, command-line

Say I do:

```bash
ls somedir
```

is there a way I could re-run it with a different command?

Example:

```
ls somedir
<run same command as above but with cd instead of ls>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `$_` is the last argument of the previous line you typed.  So, for example, `cd $_` would do what you described

```
bash-4.2$ ls X
1
bash-4.2$ cd $_
bash-4.2$ ls
1
```

There's also some command substitution options as well; eg `^` will replace commands on the previous line

```
bash-4.2$ ls X
1
bash-4.2$ ^ls^cd
cd X
bash-4.2$ ls
1
```

Comment: Damn I should've known that, I use `$_` a lot.

Comment: Also, depending on  your shell editing mode... if you've done `set -o emacs` then <ESC>. will bring the last word in.  So `ls <ESC>.`  I'm not sure there's an equivalent in `vi` mode, but I could be wrong.

Comment: are there any advantages or use cases where your 2nd option would be better? So do you mean for your emacs example that if I done `ls <ESC>` emacs would open with the `ls` output written in?

Comment: No, the <ESC>. is purely a command line "insert at this point the last word".  It actually shows up as if you've typed the last word.  It doesn't open an editor at all.

Comment: can you give an example please?